# Insert_after() function of BeautifulSoup4 works unexpectidly

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to use insert_after() function of bs4 but I can't understand why in this case it inserts  only after the second  tag? Why not after each one? If I change code to insert for example some text instead of  tag, it inserts it after each link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p><a href="http://www.foo.com">this if foo</a><a href="http://www.bar.com">this if bar</a></p>')
b = soup.new_tag('b')
for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_tag.insert_after(b)
print soup
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.foo.com">
        this if foo
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.bar.com">
        this if bar
      </a>
      <b>
      </b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could you please explain to me how I can use this function to insert after each  tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't insert *the same BeautifulSoup `Tag`* into multiple places. What happens here is that it first inserts the tag after the first link, then, on the next iteration it, basically, moves the same `b` tag after the current link.

Create new tag for every link found in the loop:

```
for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_tag.insert_after(soup.new_tag('b'))
```